# Best practices to perform CRUD operations on Entities (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to figure out where should I put database operation for each entity. Before this confusion,  for each entity, I was doing all these database operations in a provider class. Provider class means that each class has a provider. Such as:

```
class Member
{
   public string FirstName;
   public string LastName;
}

class MemberProvider
{
  //Singleton
  //Do database operations

   ......

   public List<Member> GetItems(FirstName = null, LastName = null)
   {
       // run store procedure
       //this returns List<Member> if any
   }

   public Member GetItem(int? Id = null,FirstName = null, LastName = null)
   {
       // run store procedure
       //this return Member if any
   }

   ....
}
```

then when I need a list of member with some filtering, I do this:

```
 List<Member> members = MemberProvider.Instance.GetItems(FirstName = "John", LastName = "Black");
```

The question is how can I do all this database operations related to entity in the entity itself ? Is it good practice ? What should I read to understand this concept ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the Entity Framework or some other system?

Comment: I just use EntityFramework for data access layer.

Comment: Consider using repository pattern, it will help in long run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, business objects and data access should be separated. Have a look at the Repository Pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c-sharp), and [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). This is probably exactly what you need.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use Repository pattern.
Here you are really good posts to get good introduction and sample code : [Using Repository and Unit of Work patterns with Entity Framework 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx)

and another [Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Those links are very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You should think about using the principle '[Seperation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)'. Therefore another class should be responsible for the crud operations.

You can consider to look into the Repository pattern. [Patrik Löwendahl](http://blog.lowendahl.net/?p=249) wrote an easy to read tutorial to start with.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that the database operations should be in a separate class.  Take a look at the Single Responsibility Principal http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf and the Repository design pattern http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html.